# Can't deal with some complicated laid-out content from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script in Python in combination with BeautifulSoup to parse some content from a webpage. In the landing page there are two tables. I need to use the `Results` tab from the first table which will lead to the target page.

From the target page I'm only after this information `Grade:  M   300 metres` and so on. There are multiple tabs just above it like `1,2,3,4`, etc. which have different `Grade` status. I wish to fetch them all.

As the `Results` tabs located in the landing page do not have any link connected to it, I had to use `post` request to fetch the content from the target page. Browser simulator is not an option for me in this case.

The bottom line is I need to use six `post` requests to reach the content of six `Results` tabs.

The script I'm pasting below can handle the content of the last `results` tab. How can I fix the loop to get the content from all the `Results` tab at the same time?

This is my try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.thedogs.com.au/Racing/Results.aspx?SearchDate=3-Jun-2018"

def get_info(session,link):
    session.headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0"
    res = session.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

    formdata = {}

    for items in soup.select("#aspnetForm input"):
        if "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rptrLatestRacingResults$ctl" in items.get("name"):continue
        if "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rptrSearchResults$ctl0" in items.get("name"):
            formdata[items.get("name")] = items.get("value")
        else:
            formdata[items.get("name")] = items.get("value")

    session.headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0"
    req = session.post(link,data = formdata)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
    for iteminfo in soup.select("[id^='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tabContainerRaces_tabRace'] span"):
        if "Grade:" in iteminfo.text:
            print(iteminfo.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as session:
        get_info(session,url)
```

See the two images below (one after another) to recognize the content I'm trying to fetch:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your experience here has intrigued me. Seeing the comments have being deleted, my interest has been piqued further. I've opened a question on meta to discuss this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372078/are-we-really-practicing-a-culture-of-that-what-cant-be-answered-easily-shoul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of CSS selector `span[id$=lblResultsRaceName]`, which finds all spans that's id ends with lblResultsRaceName and `'td > span'`, which finds all spans that have direct parent `<td>`:

This code snippet will go through all racing result and prints all races:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.thedogs.com.au/Racing/Results.aspx?SearchDate=3-Jun-2018"

def get_info(session,link):
    session.headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0"
    res = session.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    formdata = {i['name']: i['value'] for i in soup.select('input[type=hidden]')}
    for race_name, i in  zip(soup.select('span[id$=lblResultsRaceName]'), soup.select('input[id$=btnViewResults]')):
        print(race_name.text.strip())
        formdata[i['name']] = 'Results'
        req = session.post(link,data = formdata)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
        for panel in soup.select('div[id^=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tabContainerRaces_tabRace]'):
            print(panel.select('td > span')[0].text.strip(), panel.select('td > span')[1].text.strip())
        print('#' * 80)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as session:
        get_info(session,url)
```

Prints:

```
Healsville
Race 1 Grade:  M   300 metres
Race 2 Grade:  M   350 metres
Race 3 Grade:  6/7   350 metres
Race 4 Grade:  R/W   300 metres
Race 5 Grade:  5   350 metres
Race 6 Grade:  SE   350 metres
Race 7 Grade:  4/5   350 metres
Race 8 Grade:  SE   350 metres
Race 9 Grade:  7   300 metres
Race 10 Grade:  6/7   300 metres
Race 11 Grade:  4/5   300 metres
Race 12 Grade:  5   300 metres
################################################################################
Sale
Race 1 Grade:  M   440 metres
Race 2 Grade:  M   440 metres
Race 3 Grade:  R/W   520 metres
Race 4 Grade:  7   440 metres
Race 5 Grade:  R/W   440 metres
Race 6 Grade:  4/5   520 metres
Race 7 Grade:  R/W   440 metres
Race 8 Grade:  4/5   440 metres
Race 9 Grade:  6/7   440 metres
Race 10 Grade:  R/W   440 metres
Race 11 Grade:  R/W   440 metres
Race 12 Grade:  5   520 metres
################################################################################
...and so on.
```

Comment: It wonderfully did the trick @Andrej. Provided a plus. Gonna accept it in a while. Btw, can you provide a little description on what this line `formdata[i['name']] = 'Results'` is actually doing here? Thanks.

Comment: @asmitu With `formdata[i['name']] = 'Results'` I select which race results I want to view. I looked at it through source code in Firefox and this is the `type="submit"` form input variable.

Comment: Sorry Andrej to bother you again. It `formdata[i['name']] = 'Results'` seems to be a little advanced for me and I can't untangle the puzzle. When it has been used just before `for loop`, It gleaned some `names` and `values` in the dictionary. However, when you try like `formdata[i['name']] = 'Results'`, doesn't it grab only the word `Results` kicking out what it has been previously stored in the dictionary. Thanks again for any insight.

Comment: @asmitu I know, the old 'Results` will stay in the `formdata`, but the server will process only the last one added - it's the way how this particular server works.